# Subtraction of nested list from list doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a python newbie.
So basically I am trying to subtract a nested list from a list.
My code looks like the following:

```
k=[[1.5714285714285714, 1.6428571428571428, 1.7857142857142856],
 [2.1428571428571432, 1.285714285714286, 1.5714285714285716]] 
m=[2,1,2]

difference=[[m-k for k in l] for m,l in zip(m,k)]
difference
```

The output I get is

```
[[0.4285714285714286, 0.3571428571428572, 0.2142857142857144],
 [-1.1428571428571432, -0.28571428571428603, -0.5714285714285716]]
```

You can see clearly that subtraction doesn't work as expected because the expected output is something like this:

```
[[0.4285714285714286, -0.64285714, 0.2142857142857144],
 [-0.1428571428571432, -0.28571428571428603, 0.4285714285714826]]
```

What is wrong with my code? I am not allowed to use numpy by the way.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` in the sublist

**Ex:**

```
k=[[1.5714285714285714, 1.6428571428571428, 1.7857142857142856],
 [2.1428571428571432, 1.285714285714286, 1.5714285714285716]] 
m=[2,1,2]

difference=[[n-k for n,k in zip(m,l)] for l in k]
print(difference)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.4285714285714286, -0.6428571428571428, 0.2142857142857144],
 [-0.14285714285714324, -0.28571428571428603, 0.4285714285714284]]
```

Comment: Thank you man! Could you please tell me what is the reason behind using zip in the sublist?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
[[x-y for x,y in zip(m,k_list)] for k_list in k]
```

How does it work? The outer comprehension iterates over the sub-lists contained in k. The inner comprehension does the subtraction of the elements of m minus the elements of the k-sub-list. This is done using `zip` as already proposed in your preliminary version.